# If $b ∈ \Bbb Z$, then there is no integer a such that $b < a < b + 1$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

If $b ∈ \Bbb Z$, then there is no integer $a$ such that $b < a < b + 1.$

I am doing an introductory course for mathematical proofs and this question is an exercise related to inequalities and natural numbers.

I am having trouble articulating a proof for this proposition. I know how to prove that $b < b+1$, but I am not sure how I can prove the statement above by showing that $a$ does not exist.

Should I be doing a proof by contradiction? If I assume $a$ exists, then how do I show that this will result in contradiction? Am I supposed to try to show that $a$ is not a natural number?

I am just looking for suggestions or some instructions on how to write the proof, not an actual full written proof. I would like to be able to figure at least some of it out myself, instead of copying off of a posted answer. So please just provide helpful hints as answers.

Thank you

Comment: What axioms/properties of natural numbers are you allowed to use?

Comment: Just basic axioms such as closure under addition and multiplication, $0$ is not an element of natural numbers, and for all $a∈Z$, either $a∈N$, $a=0$, or $-a∈N$. I can also use basics of inequalities such as $a<b$ where $(b-a)∈N$

Comment: I am just looking for a very simple way to approach the proposition because this is my first time working with proofs and axioms.

Comment: I am using the textbook the Art of Proof by Allistair Savage. The assumed knowledge is known, meaning that the definitions of $N$ and properties of inequalities have been covered in class through other example proofs. (I hope I am providing adequate context)

Comment: So basically we're only allowed to use the Peano axioms

Comment: Can you claim there is no integer between $0$ and $1$?  It should be standard construction of the natural number that you start with $0$ and do successors and there'll be some axiom or principal or another to explain why you can't have an integer between $0$ and $0$'s successor.  But if you have $b < a  < b+ 1$ you will have $0 < a-b < 1$ and $a-b \in \mathbb Z$.  A contradiction.

Comment: "Just basic axioms such as closure under addition and multiplication, 0 is not an element of natural numbers, and for all a∈Z, either a∈N, a=0, or −a∈N. I can also use basics of inequalities such as a<b where (b−a)∈N "  Do you have an axiom that $1$ is the smallest natural number?  If so then $b < a < b+1 \implies b-a \in \mathbb N$ and $0 < b-a < 1$.

Comment: It really does depend though on just what axioms you have been given though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book you mentioned in a  [comment under your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008915/if-b-%E2%88%88-bbb-z-then-there-is-no-integer-a-such-that-b-a-b-1?noredirect=1#comment8274467_4008915), [*The Art of Proof*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7023-7)<sup>1</sup>, introduces the set of natural numbers in a way that is quite different from the usual one that defines the integers out of natural numbers.

To summarize,

- it first defines the integers $(\mathbf{Z},+,\cdot)$ using essentially the "ring" axioms in the first chapter.
- Then it defines the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$ as a subset of $\mathbf{Z}$ that satisfies some properties; in particular, $0\not\in\mathbf{N}$.
- Then it defines the *order* on $\mathbf{Z}$ using the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$.

And then it introduces the axiom of mathematical induction; this is the section where your exercise is in.

Your book (p.20) suggests that you should first prove the following:

> Proposition 2.21. There exists no integer $x$ such that $0<x<1$.

Proof.

Suppose there exists an integer $x$ such that $0<x<1$. Proposition 2.20 says that for all $k\in\mathbf{N}$, $k\ge 1$. Therefore we must have $x\not\in\mathbf{N}$.

On the other hand, by the definition of the order of integers (section 2.2, page 15),
$$
x=x-0\in\mathbf{N}
$$
which contradicts to $x\not\in\mathbf{N}$.

Now we prove

> Corollary 2.22 Let $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, There exists no integer $x$ such that $n<x<n+1$.

Let $P(k)$ be the statement that there exists no integer $x$ with $k-1<x<k$.
Then $P(1)$ is true by Proposition 2.21. Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and assume that $P(n)$ is true: there is no integer $x$ with $n-1<x<n$.

For sake of argument, suppose there exists an integer $x$ with $n<x<n+1$. Then
$$
n-1=n+(-1)<x+(-1)<n
$$
which contradicts the induction hypothesis. By the induction axiom 2.15, $P(k)$ is true for all $k\in\mathbf{N}$.

So far, we have shown Corollary 2.22 for all integer $n\ge 0$. Now suppose $n<0$. If there exists $x\in\mathbf{Z}$ with $n<x<n+1$, then
$$
-(n+1)<x<-n
$$
which contradicts what we have shown since $-n\in\mathbf{N}$ and $-(n+1)\in\mathbf{N}$ or $-(n+1)=0$.

---

<sup>1</sup> The authors should be Beck and Geoghegan, not Allistair Savage, who is the one wrote his [lecture notes](https://alistairsavage.ca/mat1362/notes/MAT1362-Mathematical_reasoning_and_proofs.pdf) based on the book.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really cleared up a lot of concepts mentioned in class for me! I really appreciate all of your help and the time you took to explain everything.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $a \in \mathbb{N}$. Since your inequalities give $a \gt b$, then with $b \in \mathbb{N}$, as you state in your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008915/if-b-%e2%88%88-bbb-z-then-there-is-no-integer-a-such-that-b-a-b-1#comment8274455_4008915), we have $a - b \in \mathbb{N}$. Since you also state in your comment $0$ is not an element of $\mathbb{N}$, then if you know or can assume that $1$ in the smallest natural number, we also get

$$a - b \ge 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

However, with your inequality, we would like to try to get something to compare \eqref{eq1A} against, ideally to get a contradiction. With that in mind, try subtracting $b$ from both sides of $a \lt b + 1$ to see what the result is.